# how to create an object from an array and calculate values in a new object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array where each index with the same name should be counted in the object. Please check the example and result below.
I'm trying to figure out a few things:

1. how to create two new objects "viktor" and "kate" inside the object ?
2. how to provide a calculation for each key if they are the same: "apple", "grape", "orange", "apple" and "banana" ?

```
const obj = {
  viktor: ["apple", "grape", "orange", "apple", "banana"],
  kate: ["grape", "orange", "apple", "grape", "banana"]
};

function calc(a) {
}

console.log(calc(obj));

// result of calc method should be equal to
// {
//   viktor: {
//     apple: 2,
//     grape: 1,
//     orange: 1,
//     banana: 1
//   },
//   kate: {
//     apple: 1,
//     grape: 2,
//     orange: 1,
//     banana: 1
//   }
// }
```

Comment: For this you can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: Welp, I just finished writing an answer and now the question is closed. Sorry about that. I hope you find what you're looking for.

Comment: @nullromo well... I didn't expect that this question could be closed. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @nullromo if your answer is not similar to other answers ... can you leave your version in that post? Thanks!

Comment: It's very similar to what's there already, except with a little extra logic for handling the fact that you have your lists as values in an object instead of just a single list to reduce.

Comment: @nullromo sorry, I understand how to get values from an array using reduce(). However, I don't understand how to get lists as values in an object. Can you explain? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236962/discussion-between-sweet-caramel-and-nullromo).

Comment: Sweet Caramel I added some discussion in the chat.